# Why I get different points from upvoted?

Tags: support, reputation

My answers on SuperUser get different points from upvoteds.

One get 5 points and other one get 2 points. (no downvotes)

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

Chances are these were due to the rep limit.

If you were at 195 (e.g. 18 upvotes + 1 accepted answer) the next upvote would be worth 5.

If you were then downvoted (putting you at 198) the next upvote would be worth 2.

EDIT: I hadn't spotted the 'no downvotes' bit before. Are you sure? What do my reputation tracker show? (On phone, so can't do links easily, but http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx should get you there.)

Comment: @Ian: That's not showing me anything. What are you seeing?

Comment: lol zzz I assumed SO instead of superuser, my mistake.

Comment: I thought, that accepted answer didn't count to 200 reputation day limit.

Comment: @Mic: They do if they're prior to 200. They will just count after you hit 200, as well.